# Read Mysql Database After Event came to Esper Engine?

Tags: java, mysql, esper

Hi i want to connect Esper database adapter to my application.My Application simply need when event Occurred need to get data from Database and If data in Database match with Event Data Need to parse to Update Listener.So far I have done the Read Database from Esper database Adapter.

```
select * from pattern[every timer:interval(10)] as ep , sql:cep_demo ['select * from BasicEvent where eventId = 7']
```

But the Problem is I can only read data with time interval period.But My requirement is After Event came to Esper Engine get Data from Mysql Database And If UserId in Database match with UserId in Event throw to Listener.I want to Know Is this possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from Event, sql:cep_demo ['select * from BasicEvent where eventId = 7']
```

Comment: Hi Thanks your Comment I have problem with configuration for this kind of Application.When i add EPServiceProviderManager.getDefaultProvider only i can connect database but in this configuration i can't run above query.